# Pencil Lag (iPad 2018 vs Pros, Notes vs OneNote, iOS 11 vs 12)

Tags: ios, ipad, notes.app, apple-pencil

I am very nitty about the input lag of the Apple Pencil. 
Originally, I was under the impression that the iPad 2018 was a little slower to respond. Testing was with with Standard Notes App.

I got the 2018 anyway, at this undeniable price.

I was then super surprised that in OneNote (which I prefer) the lag was much less noticeable than in Notes. So **it is a software thing**, after all!!!

With iOS 12 now, I have more lag in OneNote, while Notes is now much smoother!!!

Has anybody experienced similarly?
Any workarounds/tips?

Answer (score 1):

Based on viewing the drawing footage in slow motion, it appears the new Apple Notes app in iOS 12 is using Apple's [Predicted Touches](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_touches_in_your_view/minimizing_latency_with_predicted_touches) technology, which makes an educated guess as to where future touches on the display will appear so the developer can temporarily pre-draw the path there. This explains why the latency now appears faster than OneNote, which doesn't appear to use this technology. As far as I'm aware, previous versions of Apple Notes did not use this technology.

If you want to reduce latency for Apple Pencil input, the 2nd-generation iPad Pros are the way to go because they have the 120hz ProMotion display, versus 60hz for the 2018 iPad, though they are now well over a year old -- so maybe best to wait for an update. Alternatively, you could use [PDF Viewer by PSPDFKit](https://www.pdfviewer.io), which has the lowest latency of any app I've used because it uses more predicted touches than Apple Notes.

Comment: Interesting. I was not aware of "Predicted Touches", but somehow felt the difference. Strangely enough, my feeling also tells me that OneNote got slower/laggy with iOS12. Hope they fix it.